# CMD: Export all the screen content to a text file

Tags: command-line, cmd

In command prompt - How do I export all the content of the screen to a text file(basically a copy command, just not by using right-clicking and the clipboard)

This command works, but only for the commands you executed, not the actual output **as well**

```
doskey /HISTORY > history.txt
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to append a file instead of constantly making a new one/deleting the old one's content, use double `>` marks. A single `>` mark will overwrite all the file's content.

**Overwrite** file

```
MyCommand.exe>file.txt
```

^This will open file.txt if it already exists and overwrite the data, or create a new file and fill it with your output

**Append** file from its end-point

```
MyCommand.exe>>file.txt
```

^This will append file.txt from its current end of file if it already exists, or create a new file and fill it with your output.

---

### Update #1 (advanced):

My batch-fu has improved over time, so here's some minor updates.

If you want to differentiate between error output and normal output for a program that correctly uses [Standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams), `STDOUT`/`STDERR`, you can do this with minor changes to the syntax. I'll just use `>` for overwriting for these examples, but they work perfectly fine with `>>` for append, in regards to file-piping output re-direction.

The `1` before the `>>` or `>` is the flag for STDOUT. If you need to actually output the number one or two before the re-direction symbols, this can lead to strange, unintuitive errors if you don't know about this mechanism. That's especially relevant when outputting a single result number into a file. `2` before the re-direction symbols is for STDERR.

Now that you know that you have more than one stream available, this is a good time to show the benefits of outputting to `nul`. Now, outputting to `nul` works the same way conceptually as outputting to a file. You don't see the content in your console. Instead of it going to file or your console output, it goes into the void.

**STDERR** to file and *suppress* STDOUT

`MyCommand.exe 1>nul 2>errors.txt`

**STDERR** to file to only log errors. Will keep STDOUT in console

`MyCommand.exe 2>errors.txt`

**STDOUT** to file and *suppress* STDERR

`MyCommand.exe 1>file.txt 2>nul`

**STDOUT** *only* to file. Will keep STDERR in console

`MyCommand.exe 1>file.txt`

**STDOUT** to one file *and* **STDERR** to *another* file

`MyCommand.exe 1>stdout.txt 2>errors.txt`

The only caveat I have here is that it can create a 0-byte file for an unused stream if one of the streams never gets used. Basically, if no errors occurred, you might end up with a 0-byte errors.txt file.

### Update #2

I started noticing weird behavior when writing console apps that wrote directly to `STDERR`, and realized that if I wanted my error output to go to the same file when using basic piping, I either had to combine streams `1` and `2` or just use `STDOUT`. The problem with that problem is I didn't know about the correct way to combine streams, which is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23659304/3543437):

`%command% > outputfile 2>&1`

Therefore, if you want all **STDOUT** *and* **STDERR** piped into the same stream, make sure to use that like so:

`MyCommand.exe > file.txt 2>&1`

The redirector actually defaults to `1>` or `1>>`, even if you don't explicitly use `1` in front of it if you don't use a number in front of it, and the `2>&1` combines the streams.

## Update #3 (simple)

### Null for Everything

If you want to completely suppress STDOUT and STDERR you can do it this way. As a warning not all text pipes use STDOUT and STDERR but it will work for a vast majority of use cases.

STD* to null 
`MyCommand.exe>nul 2>&1`

### Copying a CMD or Powershell session's command output

If all you want is the command output from a CMD or Powershell session that you just finished up, or any other shell for that matter you can usually just select that console from that session, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all content, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy the content. Then you can do whatever you like with the copied content while it's in your clipboard.

Comment: I understood the question to be about copying the command prompt history to a text file. This answer seems to just be about copying the output of one command rather than a whole history of commands.

Comment: @KyleDelaney The OP wanted to know how to get both the command and the command output to a text file. This answer explains how to do that by ensuring that both STD and STDERR are being accounted for or selectively ignored, as well as helping you understand how to either start a fresh file or append an existing one. It answer's the OP's question and also clarifies use. Does that not suffice?

Comment: Well it surely suffices for the OP since your answer was selected. It's just that `doskey /HISTORY` seems to indicate that the goal was to get all commands and not just one command. Your answer being marked as correct seems to indicate that you correctly interpreted what the OP wanted to do, but it's too bad that people coming here hoping to find a way to copy the whole command prompt history won't get that.

Comment: @KyleDelaney I see what you're saying, and agree that it's too bad there wasn't already a built-in tool to achieve this, as you'd think it would be useful for stuff like tech-support. However, I do challenge the concept of not having everything from a session go to file, if done with foresight. You can do text streams from STD or STDERR against each command to achieve this effect, and if lacking the foresight to do it, I don't see why one couldn't just `CTRL` + `A` then manual copy; guessing that use-case isn't meant for pure automation, so I don't see an issue with proposing that alternative.

Answer (score 19):

Just see [this](http://www.labnol.org/software/copy-command-output-to-clipboard/2506/) page

in cmd type:

```
Command | clip
```

Then open a `*.Txt` file and `Paste`. That's it. Done.

Comment: Unfortunately does not capture stderr, 2>&1 in the accepted answer did the trick.

Answer (score 11):

**If you are looking for each command separately**

To export all the output of the command prompt in text files. Simply follow the following syntax.

```
C:> [syntax] >file.txt
```

The above command will create result of syntax in file.txt. Where new file.txt will be created on the current folder that you are in.

For example,

```
C:Result> dir >file.txt
```

**To copy the whole session, Try this:**

```
Copy & Paste a command session as follows:

1.) At the end of your session, click the upper left corner to display the menu.
Then select.. Edit -> Select all

2.) Again, click the upper left corner to display the menu.
Then select.. Edit -> Copy

3.) Open your favorite text editor and use Ctrl+V or your normal
Paste operation to paste in the text.
```

Comment: yeah I not quite what I am lookign for. I have a list of many commands that I ran, and I want to export it to a text file. I do not want to go and export the output for each different command I ran...There are too many. I want to run a bunch of command, and then export everything, at once, to a text file

Comment: thanks, but I thought there was a commmand that could do that...Not quite what I was looking for

Comment: This solution will not work well if the output is large. It will only copy the current screen content. Also you cannot scroll up the cusor on CMD to SELECT ALL. A `tree` command on C:/ drive will help you to understand.

Comment: yeah @Red ... But you can make it done by increasing buffer size.

Comment: @Jayram agree. But its inconvenient.

Comment: Yeah @Red ..It would be great if you suggest an alternative for this.

Comment: True, it works well, but I think OP is looking for something like `script` from Unix. Wish Windows had it...

Comment: i had a question, googled it, ended up in this question, skipped reading the details, looked through the answers, read this one and found what I was looking for. +1 for that. hahaha

Answer (score 3):

If your batch file is not interactive and you don't need to see it run then this should work.

```
@echo off
call file.bat >textfile.txt 2>&1
```

Otherwise use a `tee` filter.  There are many, some not NT compatible.  SFK the Swiss Army Knife has a tee feature and is still being developed.  Maybe that will work for you.

Comment: No sure what this is suppose to do..?

Comment: It creates a textfile.txt file with the cmd history inside it.

Comment: If you want the output that `SomeBatFile.bat` generates, so not a copy of the commands that `SomeBatFile.bat` executes, but the actual response on those executions, then this is your answer! Don't put this code in `SomeBatFile.bat` but create a second separate `CallSomeBatFile.bat` and put this code in there. Then Execute `CallSomeBatFile.bat`, and it works like a charm! Thank you @foxidrive!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
<command> > <filename.txt> & <filename.txt>
```

Example:

```
ipconfig /all > network.txt & network.txt
```

This will give the results in Notepad instead of the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

From command prompt Run as Administrator. Example below is to print a list of Services running on your PC run the command below:

```
net start > c:\netstart.txt
```

You should see a copy of the text file you just exported with a listing all the PC services running at the root of your `C:\` drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output **ALL** verbosity, not just *stdout*. But also any *printf* statements made by the program, any warnings, infos, etc, you have to add `2>&1` at the end of the command line.

In your case, the command will be

`Program.exe > file.txt 2>&1`