# Write std::cerr to txt file

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, output

I've added some methods to an existing project. It was writing correctly to a txt file. However i can only see my recently added std::cerr texts now, i execute my project like

```
./faceDemo > run.txt
```

What are the possible reasons?

Comment: Your error description is unclear, and you should add a minimal, reproducible example of the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wish to redirect the error flow, you should use something like that :
`./faceDemo > std.log 2> err.log`

And if you wish to redirect both flows in the same file use this :
`./faceDemo > run.txt 2>&1`

`2>&1` means redirect error flow into std flow

Comment: Wow. I didn't realize this was default required behavior. One less reason to use `std::cerr`....