# Nightwatch get the results which are printed in the console during the test in a variable

Tags: output, nightwatch.js

I would like to get the result logged in the console by Nightwatch during the test

(all the elements like " V Element was visible after 355 milliseconds.") in a variable in order to send them by email.

All the informations of the console are perfect to me so if that is possible to get them as they are it would be perfect !

thank you very much for your help !

Comment: what you are seeking for is save the terminal output to a text file, not related to the nightwatch.js itself. for windows : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042476/cmd-export-all-the-screen-content-to-a-text-file#20737973 for unix : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200637/save-all-the-terminal-output-to-a-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMD: Export all the screen content to a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042476/cmd-export-all-the-screen-content-to-a-text-file)